# Ionic 2 - Get data from the service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**THE SITUATION**:

Sorry if it is a basic question.

In my Ionic 2 app I have a POST request for the login. It is properly working. There is a form with email and password. I send this data to the API and I get as response the corresponding user data.

The only problem is that I get this data inside the service.

How can then pass this data to the loginPage component?

In the console i can see all the data properly received. Just the console.log is inside the service.

I only need to pass the data to the component.

**THE CODE**:

**The LoginPage component**:

```
makeLogin() 
{
    var email = this.loginForm.value.email.trim();
    var password = this.loginForm.value.password.trim();

    this.userService.submitLogin(email, password, this.api_access_key);

}
```

**The service**:

```
submitLogin(email: string, password: string, api_access_key: string) 
{       
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('email', email);
    urlSearchParams.append('password', password);
    urlSearchParams.append('api_access_key', api_access_key);

    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    this.http
        .post(this.loginUrl, body, { headers: headers })
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
                    console.log('login API success');
                    console.log(data);
                }, error => {
                    console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `subscribe` inside your `component` not in `service`.

// component

```
makeLogin() 
{
    var email = this.loginForm.value.email.trim();
    var password = this.loginForm.value.password.trim();

    this.userService.submitLogin(email, password, this.api_access_key).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });

}
```

// Service

```
submitLogin(email: string, password: string, api_access_key: string) 
{       
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('email', email);
    urlSearchParams.append('password', password);
    urlSearchParams.append('api_access_key', api_access_key);

    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    return this.http
        .post(this.loginUrl, body, { headers: headers })
        .map(response => response.json());
}
```

Comment: Hi Ranakrunal, when i hit post API i will get response with HTML tag like this {"_body":"<br />\"} so can you help me.